# Auto-refresh a php page after modification in other php file on a same website

Tags: php

I am having an index page which is showing the list of documents/rows available in a database.
I am having another php page which deletes the selected document/row from database.
Now my problem is after clicking on a link that I am providing with the document/row name opens details on another tab/window; so after deleting the document/row from the details view, it doesn't automatically update the 'doc/row list' page.
Is there any other option so that i can auto-update the document list after the deletion of a document/row?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: did you try to use ajax (jquery) to reload it ?

Comment: hi @MarcosBrinner, i haven't worked much on jquery. so if you can give me some example, it would be very helpful.. :)

Comment: i've added a answer bellow with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will want to close your newly opened window after the successful deletion. If that's the case then you can add following block to the success case of your row deletion page. It will refresh the parent page after your records are deleted.

```
die('<script>window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
        </script>');
```

Comment: hi @RajaAmerKhan , this code snippet is looking to work fine.. is there any option so that we can delay this action like "header('Refresh:5')" will wait for 5seconds and will go back; but its a php code, so it won't work here in case of JS. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: how about adding a little HTML after your PHP logic? Like, you close your PHP tag and add HTML, head, body etc.. tags and use JavaScript function setTimeout for the above code? setTimeout reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: it worked for me..thanks.. :)
but i was also looking for a solution in which it'll auto-update the parent page without closing the current one like we are doing in the case you explained..

Comment: glad it worked :-) please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the tick below vote arrows. Thanks.

Comment: @Swaps Well, if you don't want to close current window then simply remove window.close(); from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go  so you  will have to  'dynamic' your site it will be easy 1st copy it to your site and embed the [Jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<div id='myRows'>Here is the content where you load the rows dinamicly
    <div id='myrow1' onclick='DeleteRow(1)'>Your Row Value</a>
</div>
<script>
function DeleteRow(a){
   $.post("PageThatDeleteRow.php", rowiD:a, function(rt){
      $("#myRows").html(rt);
   });
}
</script>
```

Now I'll explain what we did 1sr we created a div with id #myRows Where we load all your rows that  you  want to show
Next inside this div we will  load the values and than insert new divs with diferentes id's as myrow1 myrow2 and  the function have the same value as id this value you will raceve it in your page php that  delete the row and in the same page you will receve a `$_POST['rowID']` on your page with the value, you have to  creat a query and output the new rows in the same page cause this  line  `$("#myrow"+a).hide();`will get the return  page and output it in your div

So if your have another question about jquery take one look at jquery documentation [click here](http://jquery.com)

Comment: The idea you explained above is great :) but i would need to modify the considerable amount of my code. The other answer worked for me. Thanks a lot. I'll definitely try the solution you provided. :)